# Find next upcoming date from specific user and from a specific product

Tags: mysql

i really need some help with my sql, i m very noob in this, so hope you guys can help.

my table look like this:

```
+-------------------------------+
| Products                      |
+-------------------------------+
| users | Product  |    Date    |
| 1     |    A     | 2022-09-10 |
| 1     |    A     | 2022-09-23 |
| 1     |    B     | 2022-09-10 |
| 2     |    A     | 2022-09-10 |
| 2     |    C     | 2022-09-10 |
+-------------------------------+
```

I need to find next upcoming date from specific user and from a specific product.
I tried this, but it wont work:

```
SELECT `date` FROM `products` WHERE `users`='1' & `Product`='A' & date(`date`) = (select min(date(`date`))
      from products
      where date(`date`) > date(now())
   )
```

Hope you can help me guys

Comment: Can you please share the expected output as well?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[Upcoming date + Specific user and product]

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM products 
WHERE users=1 AND 
      Product='A' AND
      date(`Date`) > date(now())
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: This return `1, A, 2022-09-10` https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pB6b5xrgPKCivFWcpQHsyE/10